# CAR-Algebra: Nontriviality?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{h}$.

Consider the abstract CAR-algebra $a:\mathcal{h}\to\mathcal{A}_\text{CAR}$.

Then their actually isometries:
$$a:=a(f):\quad a^*\|f\|a=a^*\{a,a^*\}a=(a^*a)^*\\\implies\|f\|^2\|a\|^2=\|f\|^2\|a^*a\|=\|(a^*a)^2\|=\|a^*a\|^2=\|a\|^4\implies\|a\|=\|f\|$$
What if before the last step:
$$f_0\neq0:\quad a(f_0)=0$$
Obviously, it holds:
$$f=0\implies a(f)=0$$
But that is not enough...

Comment: @noidentity: May I help you explain specific parts? Basically it is about the CAR-algebra - is this known to you?

Comment: @noidentity: Please, be nice. See the [guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). I flagged your comment as rude - just so you know and also in the hope that the atmosphere remains positive on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Aah, sometimes things are so simple. :)*

Suppose it vanishes: $a(f_0)=0$

Then one has by the CAR relations:
$$0=\{a(f),a(f)^*\}=\|f\|^2\neq0$$
That is a contradiction!